# Image box shadow border styling in CSS

Tags: html, css, border

I would like to achieve a CSS border similar to the one seen around the Tim Cook image on this page: http://www.macstories.net/news/tim-cook-at-d11/ — however, I would only like the border around images in the body text on my own site, not, for instance, images in the sidebar of my site.

What code would I need to achieve the cool border, and how can I target only images in the body text?

Comment: 1) - the style is right there in the source ("inspect element" in Chrome, Safari, Firebug, etc.) 2) - use a CSS selector to target only the element you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your "body text" is, say, in a div classed as "main", you can target the images just in that section like so:

```
.main img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: 30px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:auto;
    height:auto; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i think it would be something like this for just a generic shadow effct.

The HTML:

```
 <div id="example" class="outerglow">Full Shadow</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    #example {
font-size: 1.4em;
color: #CCCCCC;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #333333;
margin: 25px auto;
padding: 5px 10px;
height: 40px;
width: 80%;}


    .outerglow {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);}
```

and here is the jsfiddle to look see.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/KMtc6/

Forgive me if my code is sloppy or jumbled.